# How can I replace non-reals in a multidimensional list?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, replacement

Ok. I'm obviously not understanding something about pattern matching.

I have a list called `t` like the following:

```
t = {{3.2,5.9,Indeterminate},{4.5,-3 - 100 (1 - 2/(Underflow[] + 1)) + 200 (1 - Underflow[]),7.9},{1.2,9.1,2.3}}
```

Where I would like to use `ReplaceAll[]` to convert all non-real values to 0.0, like so:

```
{{3.2,5.9,0.0},{4.5,0.0,7.9},{1.2,9.1,2.3}}
```

How could I do this with ReplaceAll[] and pattern matching?

I have tried:

```
t /. r_ /; Head[r] != List | Real -> 0.0
```

But that does nothing to the list. I am trying to wrap my head around pattern matching, but I'm not quite there yet, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S.- I would really like to understand this in context of pattern matching, but other more efficient ways of doing this are also appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had two issues.

1. You can't use [`Unequal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal) ("!=") with [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives) ("|").
2. Even if you correct your pattern, the pattern would match the whole expression.

Using [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace) with a level spec and a corrected pattern:

```
t = {{3.2,5.9,Indeterminate},{4.5,-3-100 (1-2/(Underflow[]+1))+200 (1-Underflow[]),7.9},{1.2,9.1,2.3}};

Replace[
    t,
    r_ /; !MatchQ[Head[r], List | Real] -> 0.0,
    {2}
]
```

> {{3.2, 5.9, 0.}, {4.5, 0., 7.9}, {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}}

Another possibility:

```
Replace[
    t,
    Except[_?NumberQ] -> 0.,
    {2}
]
```

> {{3.2, 5.9, 0.}, {4.5, 0., 7.9}, {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}}

Comment: Great, thanks! That helps me to understand it a lot better

Answer (score 2):

I prepended `11`, `1/3` and `4 + 3 I` to the first sublist

```
list =
  {{11, 1/3, 4 + 3 I, 3.2, 5.9, Indeterminate},
   {4.5, -3 - 100 (1 - 2/(Underflow[] + 1)) + 200 (1 - Underflow[]), 7.9},
   {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}};
```

**1.**

`RealValuedNumberQ` (new in 13.3) gives, in my opinion, the best
solution (according to the title of the question)

```
Replace[list, Except[_?RealValuedNumberQ] -> 0., {2}]
```

{{11, 1/3, 0., 3.2, 5.9, 0.}, {4.5, 0., 7.9}, {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}}

**2.**

This replaces `11` and `1/3` (which are real numbers)

```
Replace[list, x_ /; Head[x] =!= Real -> 0., {2}]
```

{{0., 0., 0., 3.2, 5.9, 0.}, {4.5, 0., 7.9}, {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}}

**3.**

This doesn't replace `4 + 3 I`

```
Replace[list, Except[_?NumberQ] -> 0., {2}]
```

{{11, 1/3, 4 + 3 I, 3.2, 5.9, 0.}, {4.5, 0., 7.9}, {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{3.2, 5.9, Indeterminate}, {4.5, -3 - 100 (1 - 2/(Underflow[] + 1)) + 
         200 (1 - Underflow[]), 7.9}, {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}};
```

Using `Cases` and `If`:

```
Cases[#, x_ :> If[MatchQ[x, _?NumberQ], x, 0.]] & /@ list

(*{{3.2, 5.9, 0.}, {4.5, 0., 7.9}, {1.2, 9.1, 2.3}}*)
```